# want to check if a CheckBox in another fragment is Checked

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have 2 fragments and I would like to check from Fragment 1 to see if CheckBox1 in fragment 2 is checked.

**EDIT**

I am doing the following:
In the main Activity:

```
@TargetApi(11)
public class gamesmodestab extends Activity{
    public static Context appContext;

    public boolean lf_ch=false;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        appContext=this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//Then I declare the fragments and add them
```

In the Frgment were the checkbox is available:

```
@TargetApi(11)
public class tabquests extends Fragment{ 

    public CheckBox lc,
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)//onCreateView
    {

        View V=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_quests, container, false);
                lc=(CheckBox)V.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
  lc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
              @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                  if(lc.isChecked())
                      lf_ch=true;//Wrong
                  else
                      lf_ch=false;//Wrong
              }
          });
```

In the fragment where I want to read lf_ch;

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                if(lf_ch==false)//Wrong
                {
```

This is in high level what I want to do. So I would like a way to access lf_ch set on Activity or to directly access the checkbox in the 2nd fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be directly accessing the state of an input in one fragment from another.

It is better to create a activity level variable to save the boolean value indicated by the cb.

```
public boolean lf_ch = false; // default checked state.
```

Initialize the checked state of your cb to the value of your variable.

```
lc.setChecked(context.getActivity().lf_ch);
```

Then change the value of your variable when the checked state changes.

```
lc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                context.getActivity().lf_ch = isChecked;

            }});
```

Then in frag1 you can test the value of If_ch;

```
if(context.getActivity().If_ch){
    // Do something
}
```

----- EDIT -------

```
@TargetApi(11)
public class gamesmodestab extends Activity{
    public static Context appContext;

    public boolean lf_ch=false;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        appContext=this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//Then I declare the fragments and add them
In the Frgment were the checkbox is available:

@TargetApi(11)
public class tabquests extends Fragment{ 
    gamesmodestab gmt = (gamesmodestab) getActivity();
    public CheckBox lc,
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)//onCreateView
    {

        View V=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_quests, container, false);
                lc=(CheckBox)V.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
  lc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
              @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                  gmt.If_ch = isChecked;
              }
          });
```

You will need to define gmt in this class as well.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!gmt.lf_ch)
                {
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
I am trying to set lc.setChecked(context.getActivity().lf_ch); (this should be in the fragment in which it is located right?)
but I am not able to access the variable lf_ch in the activity. How can I access it?

Comment: Context context = this; In your fragment.

Comment: giving me an error: cannot convert from tabmodes to Context.
tabmodes is the name of my class