# Android: Set a checkbox to "checked" from a different fragment

Tags: java, android, checkbox, togglebutton, ischecked

is there any way to set a checkbox to "checked" from a different fragment?

I'll try to explain better; My app got different fragments, and, in every fragment there are some checkbox. I just made on the first fragment a button that re-create some of the function assigned to different checkboxes spreaded other fragments. So, is there any way to set the status of the checkboxes to checked if i tap on a button that is located on a different fragment?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059875/want-to-check-if-a-checkbox-in-another-fragment-is-checked

Comment: This isnt exactly what i was looking for... With the method described on that question he "recreate" the activity inside the fragment as Well as the checkbox! I dont need to clone the activity but just to set the state to checked!